# Add horizontal line to hoverinfo text in plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Is there a way to add an horizontal line to plotly hoverinfo box?  I want something that looks a little bit like that (the line, not the rest of the box) which was obtain with leaflet.

[image]

I thought it was possible to simply add the html tag `<hr>` but it isn't working.

Here is a RE which also shows what I tried:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(123)
dd <- data.frame(
  xx = rnorm(10),
  yy = rnorm(10),
  ff = as.factor(c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","a","b","c")),
  ss = round(runif(10, 100,1000))
)

pp <- plot_ly(data = dd,
              x = ~xx,
              y = ~yy,
              hoverinfo = 'text',
              text = ~paste(ff,
                            '</br></hr>',
                            "</br>value:", ss,
                            '</br><hr>',
                            '</br><hr><hr/>',sep=""))
add_markers(pp,mode = "markers")
```

As you can see in the figure below, the tag `<br>` is understood but not the `<hr>`.

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [help page](https://help.plot.ly/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/), only some HTML tags are supported by `plotly`:

> Plotly uses a subset of HTML tags to do things like newline (<br>),
>   bold (<b></b>), italics (<i>), and hyperlinks (<a href=’…’></a>). Tags <em>, <sup>, and <sub> are also supported.

You could [edit the `plotly.js` file](https://community.plot.ly/t/html-tags-in-annotations/3193/2) to add the missing tags. See `var TAG_STYLES` in the [source code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/5bc25b490702e5ed61265207833dbd58e8ab27f1/src/lib/svg_text_utils.js).

I considered [using LaTeX](https://plot.ly/r/LaTeX/), but unfortunately, LaTex typesetting [is currently broken](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/375).

Comment: How do you manually edit `plotly.js` when using it in shiny?  I can't find the file on my hard drive.  All I found is the link to plotly (http://127.0.0.1:6748/plotly-binding-4.7.1/plotly.js) used in the browser.  Anyway, this seems like a nice solution but will increase the maintenance work involve so I may just use three dash `---` to give and impression of a line...

Comment: @Bastien Sorry, I'm not sure how to implement the `plotly.js` edits. The `---` sounds like a good work-around. Best of luck!